# Embed a gif in VSTS Wiki

Tags: azure-devops, wiki, azure-devops-wiki

I know we are currently still in preview for VSTS wiki but I am just wondering if embedding/uploading a gif is supported. I'm looking to give our docs a little bit of extra documentation beyond just the standard image and definition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, gif is supported for VSTS Wiki page.

- If the gif file located locally, you just need to drag the `.gif` file in editor window. And the format will convert similar as below:

  ```
  ![giphy.gif](.attachments/giphy-84d10aa7-b43b-4f1c-b0c0-dd38db35fb4f.gif)
  ```
- If the gif files located in network, you can use the formate:

  ```
  ![Text](URL for the gif)
  ```

More details, you can refer the [markdown syntax for images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/collaborate/markdown-guidance#images).